# Does it have a valid mathematical meaning?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

Does the following expression:

$$2^{O(\log m)}$$

have any mathematical meaning? Is it even correct to write this? I have certain doubts.

$O(\log m)$ is not a well-defined number, so it's difficult to say what is meant by raising $2$ to this power.

Comment: This definitely has meaning. This means the order of magnitude of the function is no bigger than $2^{k\cdot\log m} for some constant k.

Comment: Order polynomial.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means by definition that it's equal to

$2^{a_m\log(m)}$, with $a_m$ a bounded sequence.

In other world, there exists $C$ such that

$0 \leq 2^{O(\log(m))} \leq 2^{C\log(m)}$

Also, notice that $2^{C\log(m)} = \exp( C \ln(2) \log(m) ) = m^{C'}$, so it's at most polynomial

Comment: Could you tell me how you moved $m$ from the exponent to the base? Why $\exp( C \ln(2) \log(m) ) = m^{C'}$? I assume $C'$ means 'just another constant'.

Comment: @user216094 :  Remember that $a^b = \exp( b \ln(a))$, so you have $\exp( C\ln(2)\log(m)) = \exp( \left( C \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(10)} \right)\ln(m) ) = m^{ \left( C \frac{\ln(2)}{\ln(10)} \right)}$

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation the definition doesn't actually say about how to interpret this in such cases, when we raise something to a power of big O.

Comment: @user216094 $f(n) = O(g(n))$ means that $f(n) = g(n)h(n)$ with $h$ a bounded function, so no matter what function $\phi$ you consider, $\phi( O(g(n)) ) = \phi( g(n) h(n)) $ with $h$ a bounded function

Comment: Definition from Wikipedia: $f(x)=O(g(x))$ if and only if there exists a positive real number $M$ and a real number $x_0$ such that
$|f(x)| \le \; M |g(x)|\text{ for all }x \ge x_0.$ You mean this definition is equivalent to the one you have given above, that is: $f(x)=O(g(x))$ if and only if $f(x)=g(x)h(x)$ where $h$ is bounded.

Comment: @user216094 : yes, it's equivalent, and a good exercise to prove it ;)